# Node generic pool error [db object already connecting, open cannot be called multiple times]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just tried to use [node pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) in my blog app, and here is my code:

**db.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    return new Db(settings.db, new Server(settings.host, Connection.DEFAULT_PORT), {safe:        true});
}
```

**post.js**

```
var Db = require('./Db');
var pool = poolModule.Pool({
    name     : 'mongoPool',
    create   : function(callback) {
        var mongodb = Db();
        callback(null, mongodb);
    },
    destroy  : function(mongodb) {
        mongodb.close();
    },
    max      : 100,
    min      : 3,
    idleTimeoutMillis : 30000,
    log      : true
});
```

**Usage**

```
pool.acquire(function (error, mongodb) {
    mongodb.open(function (error, db) {
        pool.release(mongodb)

        // do something
    });
})
```

As I set **min** property for the pool(here is 3), after I refresh the page for about 3 times, the page breaks up and alerts: db object already connecting, open cannot be called multiple times

While I set min to 5, then after I refresh for about 5 times, it breaks up again.

Why is this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you acquire an instance from the pool is checks if there a free instance and return it. If the isn't a free instance, or it didn't get the min config of instances it will create a new one with the create function.

So in your case, after 3 time (when min=3) it will return to you an instance that you use before. Meaning you going to run on it mongodb.open on the second time.

**Your mongodb.open(function (error, db) should be at the create function of the pool.**

Comment: That is reasonable. But I don't understand why can't we open it twice since every time I create a new Db instance which setting in db.js. What does return an instance used before means? thanks!

Comment: You don't create each time a new db instance.

Comment: says we set `min` to 3, thus we open three connections to the db. Once we reach the edge, a new request comes in, it will call `create` function which returns `new Db()` (which sets in db.js), isn't it?

Comment: No. After you created 3 connections, you start getting connection that were released back to the pool. Meaning, you get a connection that was created once with Db, after that you ran open on that connection and released it back to the pool. Now the connection you acquired is already open.